# Rails static models implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I'm developing a **REST API** in rails and I need to use records completely immutable, that I load from an external db o file **YAML**. 
I think the best solution is to use a gem like [static_model](http://code.quirkey.com/static_model/) but it is a old and doesn't support many-to-many relations (neither the *has_many :through* association nor the the *has_and_belongs_to_many* association).

What should I use to use a (ActiveRecord) model "static"?

Rails version: **4.1.2**

Thanks!

Comment: Is it an option to have the records in the db? That you can just use plain ActiveRecord and define the model to be readonly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is simple, you can implement many-to-many by yourself. As I see, you need only read access, should be pretty simple.

If your data can be more complicated and you need complex conditions, then use usual activerecord and make it readonly

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :readonly!

end
```